# can't get a belongs_to model to save as part of the has_one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got an Event and Activity. Each event has one activity, and the user needs to pick from a large number of activities. I've got a collection_select field that shows properly in the Event form, but it won't save. I keep getting a `Couldn't find Activity without an ID` error.

I thought that by creating the has_one belongs_to association in my models that the forms would automatically know what to do. Nope. So I started adding methods to the Events controller, not even knowing if they are correct. But things didn't break.

Now I'm thinking that I probably need to create a local variable in the form, but I've tried a dozen variations and can't get anything to work. I just end up getting other error messages.

My Event model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :date, :activity

  has_one :activity
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :attendees, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :comments
end
```

Activity model

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location, :title, :image, :image_cache

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  belongs_to :event
end
```

part of Events controller

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
  @activities = Activity.find(:all, :order => 'title')

end

def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  @activities = Activity.find(:all, :order => 'title')
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
end
```

Events form

```
<div class="field">
  <h6>When do you want to go?</h6><br />
  <%= f.text_field :date %>
</div>
<h5>Activities</h5>

<%= collection_select(:activity, :event_id, Activity.all, :id, :title, {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} ) %>


<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Wherein lies my ignorance?

Comment: Can you add details about event and activity tables.

Comment: what does this line do? @activity = Activity.find(params[:id]) why are you expecting an id in the params hash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing this you need to use a nested form structure in order to update both models at the same time.  You need to add **accepts_nested_attributes_for** to your Event model.rb file.  Below are what each of your files should look like.

Event Model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :activity

  has_one :activity
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :activity

  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :attendees, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :comments
end
```

Activity Model is good bc you already have the belongs_to event

Event Controller:

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
  activity = @event.activity.build
end

def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  if @event.save
    #etc.
  end
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>  
     <div class="field">
      <h6>When do you want to go?</h6><br />
      <%= f.text_field :date %>
    </div>

    <h5>Activities</h5>
    <%= f.fields_for :activity do |b| %>
       <!--Add whatever form input you need for your activity.--> 
       <%= b.collection_select :title %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

If you want a good walk through to look at checkout the [railscast on nested model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) forms

In response to the questions in the comments...yes I would reverse you model relationship setup so you have...

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

this way each event will have an activity_id column which will identify which activity corresponds with it and is used for rails to make the association.

Now for the many_to_many associations, which it sounds like you will need, you have two options. You can use has_many through or HABTM. The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you think you will need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. Check out this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations) for more explanation and details about all the methods these associations will create.

I always like has_many through since you always have the option to work with the relationship if you choose to in the future so here is how you would do that

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plans
  has_many :users, :through => :plans
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plans
  has_many :events, :through => :plans
end
```

You can call the relationship whatever you want, "plan" is just what I thought of first.

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed answer Molly. This was the direction I was going to try next, but I had in mind that this was more like the comments in a blog post and when I look at samples of those I don't see accepts_nested_attributes. I don't understand what the difference is yet.

Comment: One big difference with comments and a blog post is that in most cases (I assume) you are not creating the blog post and comments in the same form/at the same time.  Instead, the blog is created prior to the comments and when the comments are created later it is through a separate form.  No nested forms in this case so you dont need nested attributes.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I phrased my question clearly. The activities will be created in their own form. Then, in the events form, users will pick a date for the event, then choose one activity from the list of all existing activities, then save the event. Users won't be changing activities fields at all in the events form. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand what you are saying and even though it may seem you are just "choosing" one activity, you are still actually updating the activity object itself because you are assigning it now to the event and giving it an associated event_id. If you actually want the activity to belong_to the event then you need to have an event_id column for the activity so it can be associated with an event. HOWEVER if your plan is to have activities belonging to multiple events then you will need a many-to-many association

Comment: Man, and I thought I was starting to understand things. An event will only have one activity (therefore I thought has_one) but an activity could belong to any number of events. (Jimmy wants to go to dinner at Joe's Restaurant next Wed. Sara wants to take a different group to Joe's Restaurant in two weeks. Same activity, different events.) So I've been thinking that an event has_one activity and an activity belongs_to an event. Should I have it flipped like this: an activity has_many events, an event belongs_to an activity? I'm suddenly feeling really clueless. Sorry.

Comment: And then I have to introduce the User. Because the User creates the event. So should I really be creating a has_many through association? The user has_many events through activities? And other Users join the event (introducing yet another level of complication). Sorry to keep bothering you Molly. If you want, I'd be happy to pay for your time in helping me clear this up.

Comment: haha I'm self taught in Rails myself so I have been down that road of confusion MANY times! Hopefully my new edit will help clarify things some more. Def check out that rails guide, it has GREAT explanations.

Comment: Uhoh. Now I'm really confused. What happened to activities? Do I go with your 3 part Plans setup but add "belongs_to :activity" back into the Event class? Then pretty much ignore Plans unless I come up with a reason for it? And now I don't have a clue where to put the foreign keys.

Comment: Maybe I've confused a confusing thing. I don't need to keep track of Activities. I just want to create several dozen activities and then let a user pick one from a dropdown list in the process of creating an event. Just like a date field. A date has a day, a month, a year, but you just click on a square in a calendar and that date gets saved with the event. An activity has an image, a location, a title, but you select from a dropdown and it gets saved with an Event. There is no has_many or belongs_to or anything else going on with the date.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16518/discussion-between-mollystruve-and-charliemagee)